# Align top two flex containers, when one of the container is aligned center inside

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the code below.

I want to:

1. align the top of the placeholder image, with the top of the `Link1`.
2. the links to remain `centered`  with the `button`
3. `R1 Link and the button` to be to right

```css
.header {
  background-color:green;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 40rem;
}


.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
 
.navbar__items {
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
}

.navbar__items > * { 
 margin-right:  0.75rem; 
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 
.navbar__items & > *:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.button { 
background: red;
border-radius: .1875rem;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1rem;
letter-spacing: .0625rem;
padding: .375rem .75rem;

}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" /></div>
        <div>
          <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar__items">
              <a href="">Link 1</a>
              <a href="">Link 2</a>
              <a href="">Link 3</a>
              <a href="">Link 4</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar__items">
              <a href="">Link R1</a>
              <a class="button" href="">Button</a>
            </div>
          </div>  
        <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in<div>     
       </div> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't really understand how you want point 1 and 2 to look together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to put the button on the right you have to set your navbar to 100% and give automatic margin-right on your left nav. like in the example below.

I didn't understand what you're trying to achieve with the image so if you could give more details, I could try to help.

```css
.header {
  background-color:green;
  display: flex;
}


.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
 
.navbar__items {
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
}

.navbar__items > * { 
 margin-right:  0.75rem; 
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 
.navbar__items & > *:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.button { 
background: red;
border-radius: .1875rem;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1rem;
letter-spacing: .0625rem;
padding: .375rem .75rem;

}
.bar-left {
    margin-right: auto;
}
img{
    position:absolute;
   
    top:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <div></div>
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="bar-left navbar__items">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" />
            <a href="">Link 1</a>
            <a href="">Link 2</a>
            <a href="">Link 3</a>
            <a href="">Link 4</a>
           </div>
           <div class="navbar__items">
             <a href="">Link R1</a>
             <a class="button" href="">Button</a>
           </div>
       </div>           
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I want the top right corner of the image, to be at the same level with top left corner of 'Link1', of the letter 'L'

Comment: I edited the code, only thing I see doable is to put the image as position:absolute, and lower it with top:16px, if you center the text the img will be centered too, another way to do it would be to have no margin/padding on top of the letter "L" and also have the img be on the "roof" so they start at the same level, but here on the navbar I don't see how to do it

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your needs, this would be what you're looking for? I had to define an explicit height to your header since there's nothing in `flexbox` that can align an item to the top of other item, it can align items to the baseline, but I think that's not what you want.

So I had to allow for a size that can place the image at the end of the flex container vertically so it aligns with the top of the text. Let me know!

```css
.header {
  background-color:green;
  display: flex;
  height: 89px;
}


.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
 
.navbar__items {
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 vertical-align: text-top;
}

.navbar__items > * { 
 margin-right:  0.75rem; 
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 
.navbar__items & > *:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.button { 
background: red;
border-radius: .1875rem;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1rem;
letter-spacing: .0625rem;
padding: .375rem .75rem;

}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.image {
  display:block;
}

.box {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <div class="box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="image"/></div>
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar__items">
            <a href="">Link 1</a>
            <a href="">Link 2</a>
            <a href="">Link 3</a>
            <a href="">Link 4</a>
           </div>
           <div class="navbar__items right">
             <a href="">Link R1</a>
             <a class="button" href="">Button</a>
           </div>
       </div>           
</div>
```

Comment: yes this is what I want, unfortunately doesn't work for what I need. You set for the header the height, but I have also other elements (I added some dummy text to reflect that). This elements are in a way dynamic.  Sorry for not adding everything.

Comment: Hmm I see, maybe other option would be to add a margin top to the image so it stays aligned as well regarding of the additional text, will try to investigate for a better way to accomplish that